# Exporting ggvis plot with grouped data

Tags: r, graph, plot, statistics, ggvis

I've experienced a problem when exporting a `ggvis` plot (by using vg2png).

A simple case works nicely:

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~hp, y = ~mpg) %>% export_png()
```

However, if I want to export grouped data, I get the following error:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~hp, y = ~mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% export_png()

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vega/vega.js:4799
  var tx = vg.data[def.type]();
                            ^
TypeError: Property 'treefacet' of object #<Object> is not a function
    at vg.parse.transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vega/vega.js:4799:29)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Object.vg.parse.dataflow (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vega/vega.js:4261:34)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vega/vega.js:4234:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.vg.parse.data (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vega/vega.js:4223:16)
    at parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vega/vega.js:4788:22)
    at Object.vg.parse.spec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vega/vega.js:4794:23)
    at Object.vg.headless.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vega/vega.js:7248:12)
    at render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vega/bin/vg2png:55:15)
```

Could you suggest me any solution of this? This issue has bee reported [here](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/332) but still no solution/workaround.

### Edited

The function `export_png` exports a `PNG` or `SVG` from a ggvis object and requires that the external program `vg2png` is installed. This is part of the `vega` `node.js` module. This information is obtained from `?export_png`.

Comment: What is `vg2png`? I found it somewhere on GH, but it still doesn't work. You really need to make this question reproducible by adding all the packages/dependencies